# Jenkins pipeline log file seperation by parallel stages

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a complex build pipeline scripts which have some parallel steps. Im building few repos with maven in parallel (with debug and stack trace -Xe ) which generate a lot of output, the navigation is almost impossible because.

1. The console output page is huge ( > 50MB )
2. The parallel builds log message interleaved
3. slow and almost impossible

i can think of redirecting each maven build to a seperate log file, and publish the logs as build-artifacts, but im sure there is more clean/plugin way to achieve this behavior.

any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

I went down the same path. Inside `parallel`, I'm archiving the log file as artifact so that they can later be downloaded separately. Of course, it's a bit of an abuse of this functionality.

With the new Blue Ocean UI, you see the log output separated per node in a parallel execution. I'm just not sure, how much fun it will be to scroll through a log of that size.